# Heading not staying in the absolute position when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to create a description box for a website in React. The image below is the desired look:

[image]
but when I resize the screen to be large, the h1 tag doesn't seem to hold its absolute position anymore. I would like the box to resize like it has with the screen but the "Project 1" title should stay in the same place.

[image]

The CSS code to produce the images is:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.top {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #69143a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10% 25px 0;
}

.supervisor {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  color: #353535;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #353535;
}

.info {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.subjects {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

and the React component is:

```
function Project(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="top">
        <h2 className="name">{props.title}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        <h4 className="supervisor">Supervisor: {props.supervisor}</h4>
        <p className="info">{props.description}</p>
        <p className="subjects">Prerequisites: {props.subjects}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - been banging my head on the wall all day trying to get it to format correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue is the dynamic `margin` you had set on `.name`. You can remove that and also remove the `position: absolute;` and exchange it with `relative`. Then remove the top padding on `.card` and you are good to go.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #69143a;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
}

.supervisor {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  color: #353535;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #353535;
}

.info {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.subjects {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="top">
    <h2 class="name">{props.title}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h4 class="supervisor">Supervisor: {props.supervisor}</h4>
    <p class="info">{props.description}</p>
    <p class="subjects">Prerequisites: {props.subjects}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh what a legend - thanks so much.